# Is there any possibility to receive the System Requirements with the Steam Web API?

Tags: steam-web-api

Well, the question is mostly in the title.

I want to get the System Requirements of games and would love to do this without scraping. Is it possible or should I scrape the store pages of the games?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you pick a game_id (sku), lets say Half-life and call the API using the following URL

https://store.steampowered.com/api/appdetails/?appids=220

Then you get a bunch of json back

It should be of the form:

```
{
"220": {
    "success": true,
    "data": {
        "type": "game",
        "name": "Half-Life 2",
        "steam_appid": 220,
        "required_age": 0,
        "is_free": false,
        "dlc": [323140],
        "detailed_description": "1998. HALF-LIFE sends a shock through the game industry with its combination of pounding action and continuous, immersive storytelling. Valve's debut title wins more than 50 game-of-the-year awards on its way to being named \"Best PC Game Ever\" by PC Gamer, and launches a franchise with more than eight million retail units sold worldwide.<br><br>\n\t\tNOW. By taking the suspense, challenge and visceral charge of the original, and adding startling new realism and responsiveness, Half-Life 2 opens the door to a world where the player's presence affects everything around him, from the physical environment to the behaviors even the emotions of both friends and enemies.<br><br>\n\t\tThe player again picks up the crowbar of research scientist Gordon Freeman, who finds himself on an alien-infested Earth being picked to the bone, its resources depleted, its populace dwindling. Freeman is thrust into the unenviable role of rescuing the world from the wrong he unleashed back at Black Mesa. And a lot of people he cares about are counting on him.<br><br>\n\t\tThe intense, real-time gameplay of Half-Life 2 is made possible only by Source&reg;, Valve's new proprietary engine technology. Source provides major enhancements in:<br><br>\n\t\t<ul>\n\t\t<li><span class=\"copyHead\">Characters:<\/span> Advanced facial animation system delivers the most sophisticated in-game characters ever seen. With 40 distinct facial \"muscles,\" human characters convey the full array of human emotion, and respond to the player with fluidity and intelligence.<\/li>\n\t\t<li><span class=\"copyHead\">Physics:<\/span> From pebbles to water to 2-ton trucks respond as expected, as they obey the laws of mass, friction, gravity, and buoyancy.<\/li>\n\t\t<li><span class=\"copyHead\">Graphics:<\/span> Source's shader-based renderer, like the one used at Pixar to create movies such as Toy Story&reg; and Monster's, Inc.&reg;, creates the most beautiful and realistic environments ever seen in a video game.<\/li>\n\t\t<li><span class=\"copyHead\">AI:<\/span> Neither friends nor enemies charge blindly into the fray. They can assess threats, navigate tricky terrain, and fashion weapons from whatever is at hand.<\/li>\n\t\t<\/ul>",
        "about_the_game": "1998. HALF-LIFE sends a shock through the game industry with its combination of pounding action and continuous, immersive storytelling. Valve's debut title wins more than 50 game-of-the-year awards on its way to being named \"Best PC Game Ever\" by PC Gamer, and launches a franchise with more than eight million retail units sold worldwide.<br><br>\n\t\tNOW. By taking the suspense, challenge and visceral charge of the original, and adding startling new realism and responsiveness, Half-Life 2 opens the door to a world where the player's presence affects everything around him, from the physical environment to the behaviors even the emotions of both friends and enemies.<br><br>\n\t\tThe player again picks up the crowbar of research scientist Gordon Freeman, who finds himself on an alien-infested Earth being picked to the bone, its resources depleted, its populace dwindling. Freeman is thrust into the unenviable role of rescuing the world from the wrong he unleashed back at Black Mesa. And a lot of people he cares about are counting on him.<br><br>\n\t\tThe intense, real-time gameplay of Half-Life 2 is made possible only by Source&reg;, Valve's new proprietary engine technology. Source provides major enhancements in:<br><br>\n\t\t<ul>\n\t\t<li><span class=\"copyHead\">Characters:<\/span> Advanced facial animation system delivers the most sophisticated in-game characters ever seen. With 40 distinct facial \"muscles,\" human characters convey the full array of human emotion, and respond to the player with fluidity and intelligence.<\/li>\n\t\t<li><span class=\"copyHead\">Physics:<\/span> From pebbles to water to 2-ton trucks respond as expected, as they obey the laws of mass, friction, gravity, and buoyancy.<\/li>\n\t\t<li><span class=\"copyHead\">Graphics:<\/span> Source's shader-based renderer, like the one used at Pixar to create movies such as Toy Story&reg; and Monster's, Inc.&reg;, creates the most beautiful and realistic environments ever seen in a video game.<\/li>\n\t\t<li><span class=\"copyHead\">AI:<\/span> Neither friends nor enemies charge blindly into the fray. They can assess threats, navigate tricky terrain, and fashion weapons from whatever is at hand.<\/li>\n\t\t<\/ul>",
        "short_description": "1998. HALF-LIFE sends a shock through the game industry with its combination of pounding action and continuous, immersive storytelling. Valve's debut title wins more than 50 game-of-the-year awards on its way to being named \"Best PC Game Ever\" by PC Gamer, and launches a franchise with more than eight million retail units sold worldwide.",
        "supported_languages": "English<strong>*<\/strong>, French<strong>*<\/strong>, German<strong>*<\/strong>, Italian<strong>*<\/strong>, Korean<strong>*<\/strong>, Spanish - Spain<strong>*<\/strong>, Russian<strong>*<\/strong>, Simplified Chinese, Traditional Chinese, Dutch, Danish, Finnish, Japanese, Norwegian, Polish, Portuguese, Swedish, Thai<br><strong>*<\/strong>languages with full audio support",
        "header_image": "https:\/\/steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net\/steam\/apps\/220\/header.jpg?t=1541802014",
        "website": "http:\/\/www.half-life2.com",
        "pc_requirements": {
            "minimum": "<strong>Minimum:<\/strong><br><ul class=\"bb_ul\"><li><strong>OS:<\/strong> Windows 7, Vista, XP<br><\/li><li><strong>Processor:<\/strong> 1.7 Ghz<br><\/li><li><strong>Memory:<\/strong> 512 MB RAM<br><\/li><li><strong>Graphics:<\/strong> DirectX 8.1 level Graphics Card (requires support for SSE)<br><\/li><li><strong>Storage:<\/strong> 6500 MB available space<\/li><\/ul>"
        },
        "mac_requirements": {
            "minimum": "<strong>Minimum:<\/strong><br><ul class=\"bb_ul\"><li><strong>OS:<\/strong> Leopard 10.5.8, Snow Leopard 10.6.3, or higher<br><\/li><li><strong>Memory:<\/strong> 1 GB RAM<br><\/li><li><strong>Graphics:<\/strong> Nvidia GeForce8 or higher, ATI X1600 or higher, Intel HD 3000 or higher<\/li><\/ul>"
        },
        "linux_requirements": [],
        "developers": ["Valve"],
        "publishers": ["Valve"],
        "demos": [{
                "appid": 219,
                "description": ""
            }
        ],
        "price_overview": {
            "currency": "GBP",
            "initial": 719,
            "final": 719,
            "discount_percent": 0,
            "initial_formatted": "",
            "final_formatted": "\u00a37.19"
        },
        "packages": [36, 289444, 469],
        "package_groups": [{
                "name": "default",
                "title": "Buy Half-Life 2",
                "description": "",
                "selection_text": "Select a purchase option",
                "save_text": "",
                "display_type": 0,
                "is_recurring_subscription": "false",
                "subs": [{
                        "packageid": 36,
                        "percent_savings_text": "",
                        "percent_savings": 0,
                        "option_text": "Half-Life 2 - \u00a37.19",
                        "option_description": "",
                        "can_get_free_license": "0",
                        "is_free_license": false,
                        "price_in_cents_with_discount": 719
                    }, {
                        "packageid": 289444,
                        "percent_savings_text": "",
                        "percent_savings": 0,
                        "option_text": "Half-Life 2 - Commercial License - \u00a37.19",
                        "option_description": "",
                        "can_get_free_license": "0",
                        "is_free_license": false,
                        "price_in_cents_with_discount": 719
                    }, {
                        "packageid": 469,
                        "percent_savings_text": "",
                        "percent_savings": 0,
                        "option_text": "The Orange Box - \u00a315.49",
                        "option_description": "",
                        "can_get_free_license": "0",
                        "is_free_license": false,
                        "price_in_cents_with_discount": 1549
                    }
                ]
            }
        ],
        "platforms": {
            "windows": true,
            "mac": true,
            "linux": true
        },
        "metacritic": {
            "score": 96,
            "url": "https:\/\/www.metacritic.com\/game\/pc\/half-life-2?ftag=MCD-06-10aaa1f"
        },
        "categories": [{
                "id": 2,
                "description": "Single-player"
            }, {
                "id": 22,
                "description": "Steam Achievements"
            }, {
                "id": 29,
                "description": "Steam Trading Cards"
            }, {
                "id": 13,
                "description": "Captions available"
            }, {
                "id": 18,
                "description": "Partial Controller Support"
            }, {
                "id": 23,
                "description": "Steam Cloud"
            }, {
                "id": 16,
                "description": "Includes Source SDK"
            }
        ],
        "genres": [{
                "id": "1",
                "description": "Action"
            }
        ],
        "screenshots": [{
                "id": 0,
                "path_thumbnail": "https:\/\/steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net\/steam\/apps\/220\/0000001864.600x338.jpg?t=1541802014",
                "path_full": "https:\/\/steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net\/steam\/apps\/220\/0000001864.1920x1080.jpg?t=1541802014"
            }, {
                "id": 1,
                "path_thumbnail": "https:\/\/steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net\/steam\/apps\/220\/0000001865.600x338.jpg?t=1541802014",
                "path_full": "https:\/\/steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net\/steam\/apps\/220\/0000001865.1920x1080.jpg?t=1541802014"
            }, {
                "id": 2,
                "path_thumbnail": "https:\/\/steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net\/steam\/apps\/220\/0000001866.600x338.jpg?t=1541802014",
                "path_full": "https:\/\/steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net\/steam\/apps\/220\/0000001866.1920x1080.jpg?t=1541802014"
            }, {
                "id": 3,
                "path_thumbnail": "https:\/\/steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net\/steam\/apps\/220\/0000001867.600x338.jpg?t=1541802014",
                "path_full": "https:\/\/steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net\/steam\/apps\/220\/0000001867.1920x1080.jpg?t=1541802014"
            }, {
                "id": 4,
                "path_thumbnail": "https:\/\/steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net\/steam\/apps\/220\/0000001868.600x338.jpg?t=1541802014",
                "path_full": "https:\/\/steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net\/steam\/apps\/220\/0000001868.1920x1080.jpg?t=1541802014"
            }, {
                "id": 5,
                "path_thumbnail": "https:\/\/steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net\/steam\/apps\/220\/0000001869.600x338.jpg?t=1541802014",
                "path_full": "https:\/\/steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net\/steam\/apps\/220\/0000001869.1920x1080.jpg?t=1541802014"
            }, {
                "id": 6,
                "path_thumbnail": "https:\/\/steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net\/steam\/apps\/220\/0000001870.600x338.jpg?t=1541802014",
                "path_full": "https:\/\/steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net\/steam\/apps\/220\/0000001870.1920x1080.jpg?t=1541802014"
            }, {
                "id": 7,
                "path_thumbnail": "https:\/\/steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net\/steam\/apps\/220\/0000001871.600x338.jpg?t=1541802014",
                "path_full": "https:\/\/steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net\/steam\/apps\/220\/0000001871.1920x1080.jpg?t=1541802014"
            }, {
                "id": 8,
                "path_thumbnail": "https:\/\/steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net\/steam\/apps\/220\/0000001872.600x338.jpg?t=1541802014",
                "path_full": "https:\/\/steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net\/steam\/apps\/220\/0000001872.1920x1080.jpg?t=1541802014"
            }
        ],
        "movies": [{
                "id": 904,
                "name": "Half-Life 2 Trailer",
                "thumbnail": "https:\/\/steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net\/steam\/apps\/904\/movie.jpg?t=1507237301",
                "webm": {
                    "480": "http:\/\/steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net\/steam\/apps\/904\/movie480.webm?t=1507237301",
                    "max": "http:\/\/steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net\/steam\/apps\/904\/movie_max.webm?t=1507237301"
                },
                "highlight": true
            }, {
                "id": 5724,
                "name": "Free Yourself",
                "thumbnail": "https:\/\/steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net\/steam\/apps\/5724\/movie.293x165.jpg?t=1507237311",
                "webm": {
                    "480": "http:\/\/steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net\/steam\/apps\/5724\/movie480.webm?t=1507237311",
                    "max": "http:\/\/steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net\/steam\/apps\/5724\/movie_max.webm?t=1507237311"
                },
                "highlight": false
            }
        ],
        "recommendations": {
            "total": 49439
        },
        "achievements": {
            "total": 33,
            "highlighted": [{
                    "name": "Defiant",
                    "path": "https:\/\/steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net\/steamcommunity\/public\/images\/apps\/220\/hl2_hit_cancop_withcan.jpg"
                }, {
                    "name": "Submissive",
                    "path": "https:\/\/steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net\/steamcommunity\/public\/images\/apps\/220\/hl2_put_canintrash.jpg"
                }, {
                    "name": "Malcontent",
                    "path": "https:\/\/steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net\/steamcommunity\/public\/images\/apps\/220\/hl2_escape_apartmentraid.jpg"
                }, {
                    "name": "What cat?",
                    "path": "https:\/\/steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net\/steamcommunity\/public\/images\/apps\/220\/hl2_break_miniteleporter.jpg"
                }, {
                    "name": "Trusty Hardware",
                    "path": "https:\/\/steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net\/steamcommunity\/public\/images\/apps\/220\/hl2_get_crowbar.jpg"
                }, {
                    "name": "Barnacle Bowling",
                    "path": "https:\/\/steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net\/steamcommunity\/public\/images\/apps\/220\/hl2_kill_barnacleswithbarrel.jpg"
                }, {
                    "name": "Anchor's Aweigh!",
                    "path": "https:\/\/steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net\/steamcommunity\/public\/images\/apps\/220\/hl2_get_airboat.jpg"
                }, {
                    "name": "Heavy Weapons",
                    "path": "https:\/\/steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net\/steamcommunity\/public\/images\/apps\/220\/hl2_get_airboatgun.jpg"
                }, {
                    "name": "Vorticough",
                    "path": "https:\/\/steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net\/steamcommunity\/public\/images\/apps\/220\/hl2_find_vortigauntcave.jpg"
                }, {
                    "name": "Revenge!",
                    "path": "https:\/\/steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net\/steamcommunity\/public\/images\/apps\/220\/hl2_kill_chopper.jpg"
                }
            ]
        },
        "release_date": {
            "coming_soon": false,
            "date": "16 Nov, 2004"
        },
        "support_info": {
            "url": "http:\/\/steamcommunity.com\/app\/220",
            "email": ""
        },
        "background": "https:\/\/steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net\/steam\/apps\/220\/page_bg_generated_v6b.jpg?t=1541802014",
        "content_descriptors": {
            "ids": [],
            "notes": null
        }
    }
}
```

}

You can see in this data that there are pc_requirements, mac_requirements and linux_requirements properties in the returned JSON.

HTH.

Comment: Thanks for this API link. I didn't even know this part of the API as it works without a key and is not documented! How did you find it?

Comment: A number of people have tried to document what they have found. e.g. https://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/User:RJackson/StorefrontAPI